# Is it a big error to omit some limitations of research in cv but explain it in the personal statement?

Tags: phd, application

I recently encountered some phd application materials that made me a little bit annoyed. In some applicant's cv, under it's research subject he (or she) said (for example) "designed polynomial time algorithm for graph isomorphism". While when I read the personal statement, it said the algorithm only works for some specific graphs, which is, in my opinion, a trivial result. The explanation is clear but not especially emphasized. But there seems to be no other errors in his application materials and they seem to be consistent (and actually, good). I wonder what  you think of it and whether this is a big or tolerable problem.
Thanks.

Comment: In which field of science is the relevant research group active?

Comment: I feel that the issue is not about limitations, but about an inappropriate representation of what the research achieved: for the well-known graph isomorphism problem, an algorithm that only works in some cases is not a "solution with limitations", but a non-solution. I would be a little bit annoyed, too, but tolerate it if the other materials are very good.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe this is field-specific, but

> designed polynomial time algorithm for graph isomorphism

sounds to me like a completely CV-appropriate description of a project despite limitations on which graphs the algorithm applies to. CVs are never complete descriptions of work, and every work has limitations or assumptions that must be met.  If anything, it sounds extremely thorough to me that the limitations were mentioned in a personal statement. If you are interested in the limitations and scope of the work, you have to read the actual publications and judge from there.

Comment: Good answer.  I'd say the CV should have less descriptive detail, not more.